# MySQL Error: Operand Should Contain at least 1 column (Comma vs Point)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT (0,14285714285714285714285714285714*(5 - 2) + 2)
```

What does this mean?

The actual line giving me trouble is:

```
SET @a13 = (0,14285714285714285714285714285714*(@a - @tmpv) + @tmpv)
```

Both @a and @tmpv have been calculated previously in the trigger

Any insight would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your query: You use the comma as a decimal separator. You have to use a dot instead. This works just fine:

```
SELECT ( 0.14285714285714285714285714285714 * ( 5 -2 ) +2 )
```